# Developing shopping web app

Tags: php, content-management-system, shopping-cart

What web software systems of frameworks are necessary to develop a web application that has catalog of products and allows them to be buyed, using shopping cart and payment methods like, paypal, debit cards, credit cards etc...

The technology I am asking is php.

For example If I am developing system like this, can I finish the job using only Drupal or Joomla? What other subsystems should be added? Can someone give me examples? Or maybe using some CRM system?

I prefer opensource soulutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Opencart. It also supports multiple stores. And it is done in PHP so it covers all your intentions. You didn't say if you want to be open source. Opencart is opensource. Shopify could be a solution too, but it is not free.

http://www.opencart.com/

http://www.shopify.com/

Comment: So all the cms stuff is handled by this opencart system? I dont have to fuse with cms systems like Drupal or Joomla?

Comment: I don't think so, if you want supporting blog or website, you will have to fuse, but if you don't open cart does everything for I used it last month to create a web shop for fishermans, the clients were satisfied

Comment: If you want you can see the demos. There are demos on the opencarts website.

Comment: Use shopify, save your self time and headaches. Trust me, I've done both.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/). It includes everything you are looking for, and it's open source.

For instance, take a look about the payment functionality:

- Accept numerous offline payment processing (cheque, money orders, offline credit care processing, ..)
- Accept numerous online payment processing (PayPal, 2CheckOut, Authorize.net, iPayment, ..)
- Disable certain payment services based on a zone basis